# Access Rails ActiveRecord db in production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, production-environment

I've just deployed my first app to production. It's a simple front end for managing a DB, and the real action for the app happens in a script I placed in `app/` called `validation_script.rb`.  It accesses elements in the DB using ActiveRecord and performs actions based on their values.  When I was developing, I would test the script by:

```
rails runner app/validation_script.rb
```

This ran without any problems on my local machine.  But now that I have pushed this onto the hosting server and into production mode, running that same command on the server doesn't access the elements in the ActiveRecord DB.  I set my environment in `environment.rb` to `ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'production'`.  Are there any other settings I'm missing in order to connect to the production DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
rails runner -e production app/validation_script.rb
```

Comment: That works, thanks.  Is this more of a workaround, or is this the only way of accomplishing this?

Comment: I believe this is the accepted way of doing this. Documented command-line options are generally considered as a public API, be liberal in their use ;-)